# How to elevate permission in JSOM code to access SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, json

How to elevate permission in JSOM code to get permission to do Add/Edit/Update operation on SharePoint list? (similar to RunWithElevatedPriviledges in SSOM).
If elevation is not possible then my question is how to do Add/Edit/Update/Delete operation on a list access to which is highly restricted and which can be accessed only by senior managers?

Comment: You can't elevate permissions in JSOM, as @uberz91 already explained on your previous question

Comment: Just a note, it is possible to use app-only permissions, although it must be run server-side (can be externally) and operations will _not_ be run on behalf of any user.

Comment: What is JSON code? JSON is a notation for transferring data, not a programming language. Hence I took for granted you where talking about JSOM (but made a typo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SharePoint way is to create a dropoff List and use a Workflow with elevated permissions to transfer the data to the main list.

For Documents Microsoft has even built the whole **Content Organizer** for you
https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/sharepoint-2010-content-organizer-part-1-a-cool-new-feature-for-managing-your-content/

Answer (score 0):

That's definetely not possible, "by design", since it would mean anyone, from the client-side, could elevate privilèges and gain access to any content!
Only server code can elevate privileges. Thus, the only option would be to host a custom service on the server, and call it from the client. Your custom service would then be responsible to check whether the client call is legitimate or not.

Comment: my question is since JSON code cann't be elevated how to do Add/Edit/Update/Delete operation on a list access to which is highly restricted and which can be accessed only by senior managers? I am updating the main question.

Comment: @evariste is correct. That would be a huge security loophole. My answer would be develop a web service to do a CRUD operations and then call that from the client side JSON.

Comment: @user17251: yup, we had a good understanding of your question. Unfortunately, our answer does not vary... You can try whatever you want, any client-side code (naturally running under the identity of the connecter user) will never do an elevation. The only way is to create a Web service and manually check conditions where the client is authorized to run it (or else, anyone could call it). The only other option (and completely unsecured) method woud be to embed credentials of another account in the client code. I'm even a bit ashamed of mentioning this...